# How can I make text drop down to a second line using media queries?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

When my site is at a specific size I want the logo to break in half so that Photography & Design are on a second line. How would I accomplish this?

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 424px) {
    
}
```

```html
<nav>
        <h1 class="logo">Brian Funderburke Photography &amp; Design</h1>  
</nav>
```

Comment: Is it an image or text?  Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to add a span that wraps around what you want to be on its own line, then target it, and assign it `display: block;`

I highly recommend you make this more robust with proper class name selection and so forth.

HTML:

```
<nav>
  <h1 class="logo">Brian Funderburke <span>Photography &amp; Design</span></h1>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 424px) {
  .logo span {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6vcbdqqk/

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I didn't think of this. Never actually had to use the span tag before so it didn't really cross my mind. Thought of using a <div> or something, but figured that wouldn't be the best element.

Answer (score 1):

if it is only about this very `h1` and this very text, then set a `width` to force text to wrap.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 424px) {
  h1 {
    width: 10em;
  }
}
.demo {
  width: 10em;
  border: solid;
  /* remove this, demo purpose */
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <h1 class="logo">Brian Funderburke Photography &amp; Design</h1> 
</nav>
<p>below for demo</p>
<h2 class="demo">Brian Funderburke Photography &amp; Design</h2> 
<h3 class="demo">Brian Funderburke Photography &amp; Design</h3> 
<p class="demo">Brian Funderburke Photography &amp; Design</p>
```